# How Do I Enable and Disable Text In Unity Ui?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

Hi I am trying to make some popup instructions I want to disable the text when the person presses a key how might I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Namespace for Unity's UI system

public class EnableAndDisableText : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] Text text; // Text that you want to disable

    private void Update() // Called every frame
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) // If the 'E' key is pressed,
        {
            text.enabled = false; // Disable text
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I got a error
 ```error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `text.SetActive(false);` could work?
or `Destroy(text);`?

I see the question is 3 months old but I hope this still helps;

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) // If the 'A' key is pressed
    {
        text.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```